# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error about ServletUtilities

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, http-status-code-500

I am trying to make a Web Service using Tomcat 10 and jdk11 on centos.

but I got HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error, and show An error occurred at line: [703] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]

It's  said The method saveChartAsPNG(JFreeChart, int, int, ChartRenderingInfo, HttpSession) in the type ServletUtilities is not applicable for the arguments (JFreeChart, int, int, null, HttpSession)

[image]

my code as below,

```
ValueAxis   rangeAxis   =   plot.getRangeAxis();   
rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(1);

String filename = ServletUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(chart, 200, 160, null, session);
String graphURL = request.getContextPath()+"/DisplayChart?filename="+filename;
```

Please anyone can tell me what to do to fix this?

Comment: Err, provide a ChartRenderingInfo value?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/servlet/ServletUtilities.html#saveChartAsPNG-org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart-int-int-org.jfree.chart.ChartRenderingInfo-javax.servlet.http.HttpSession-), nulls are allowed for ChartRenderingInfo in 'saveChartAsPNG', so check if your other object parameters (JFreeChart and HttpSession) are the ones expected, as in package, versions etc.